# SQL Function returning a View or Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One is a reference table which contains a group of string names `TubName`:

```
| Id |  SiteID | TubName | TubVol |
|----|---------|---------|--------|
|  1 | Site001 |   Tub 1 |   1000 |
|  2 | Site001 |   Tub 2 |   1000 |
|  3 | Site001 |   Tub 3 |   1000 |
|  4 | Site001 |   Tub 4 |   1000 |
|  5 | Site001 |   Tub 5 |   1000 |
|  6 | Site001 |   Tub 6 |   1000 |
```

Each day a report is run which shows which `TubName`s are present:

```
| Id |  SiteID |     Date |   Tub |
|----|---------|----------|-------|
|  1 | Site001 | 20/06/15 | Tub 1 |
|  2 | Site001 | 20/06/15 | Tub 1 |
|  3 | Site001 | 20/06/15 | Tub 3 |
|  4 | Site001 | 20/06/15 | Tub 4 |
|  5 | Site001 | 20/06/15 | Tub 5 |
```

If the two tables are compared then `Tub 2` and `Tub 6` is not present.

I have created the simple query which returns the "untested" tubs:

```
SELECT r.TubName
FROM Tubs r 
WHERE TubName NOT IN(SELECT b.Tub FROM Tests b where SiteID = 'Site001' AND Date = '20/06/15')
```

What I really want is a function whereby I can programmatically input the `SiteID` and `Date` as arguments. I have tried something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TubsNotTested](@id nvarchar(128), @testdate nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS view
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT r.TubName 
        FROM [dbo].[Tubs] r 
        WHERE TubName NOT IN(
            SELECT b.Tub 
            FROM dbo.Tests b 
            where(SiteID = id AND Date = testdate)
        )
    )
END
```

But I get the error when a `table` is the returned object:

> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

Or this when I try and return a `View`:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'view'.

Comment: It should be "returns table" instead of view and no begin / end. Also, you probably should use the variables for something

Comment: SQL Server has pretty good documentation on creating table-valued functions (such as https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx).  `RETURNS view` is not among the options.

Comment: The Begin and the end is quite ok. :-) It's needed. But he hasn't defined his return table and tried directly to return the result. I've added my solution example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TubsNotTested](@id nvarchar(128), @testdate nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN(
    SELECT r.TubName 
    FROM [dbo].[Tubs] r 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT b.Tub 
        FROM dbo.Tests b 
        WHERE (SiteID = @id AND Date = @testdate)
    ) as tubs
        ON r.TubName = b.Tub
    WHERE tubs.Tub IS NULL
)
```

If you need to put further logic into your function, you can build a multistatement function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TubsNotTested](@id nvarchar(128), @testdate nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS @result TABLE(
    TubName nvarchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @result(TubName)
    SELECT r.TubName 
    FROM [dbo].[Tubs] r 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT b.Tub 
        FROM dbo.Tests b 
        WHERE (SiteID = @id AND Date = @testdate)
    ) as tubs
        ON r.TubName = b.Tub
    WHERE tubs.Tub IS NULL

    RETURN
END
```

But by the way. Be careful. SQL Server function, can be a bottleneck on bigger requests. Keep this in mind.

Comment: No need for a multistatement TVF here. Inline ones should generally be preferred.

Comment: Yes, but it's not clear for me if it is everything. But anyway. I won't use functions at all. Normally I could solve an issue without functions in SQL Server and those solutions are often extremely faster. :-) But that's caused by the design of SQL Server functions. :-)

Comment: No problem. By the way. If your new to Management Studio go to `View` > `Template Explorer`. It will provide you with many useful templates to start new functions, procedures, tables, etc. If your not so experienced, this will work like a charm for you. :-)

Comment: One thing left. I changed the code of your function to a `LEFT JOIN` in my last edit. This will perform better if you have a bigger `dbo.Tests` table. Otherwise, if it's returning a huge amount of `b.Tub`, the performance would be decreased. Maybe this is something you want to add to your code.

Comment: Your inline example is incorrect. It shouldn't have any insert. There is no left join currently in your answer. `not exists` is generally better performing anyway.

Comment: Ah sorry. Thanks for the hint. It's late here. :-) 
But anyway, not exists won't perform better. I had to change many queries of some older colleagues who used to use exists intensively. Most of them perform good on small data sources. As our databases exceed the terrabytes, they run nearly forever (1h and above) while the simpler left join performs good on small and bigger data sources. The same query just changed to a left join performed in 8 minutes now. :-) Just for you as a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `RETURNS view`, you also need to specify the parameters correctly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TubsNotTested](@id nvarchar(128), @testdate nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN(SELECT r.TubName 
       FROM [dbo].[Tubs] r 
       WHERE TubName NOT IN (
            SELECT b.Tub 
            FROM dbo.Tests b 
            where(SiteID = @id AND Date = @testdate)
           )
      );
```

The `BEGIN`/`END` are unnecessary for an inline table-valued function.